How to develop locally for NPM but include the package in package.json
There are numerous posts on how to work on a npm module locally but when I do package.json settings no longer have a reference to the remote module?
The guide goes like this:

in your npm package project (your npm library) use npm link. this makes the project available globally
in your project uninstall the remote repository npm uninstall myModule (this step implied or inferred)
in your project use npm link myModule. that includes it in the node_modules folder

That works. I now can update and connect to the npm module and make changes to it. But now package.json does not have the npm module mentioned anywhere.
When I uninstalled the remote published repository it removes the reference from package.json. Now others working on the project will not have access to the library when they run npm install. I don't want to break anything. Can I have both installed?
I need to have a local for editing the library and remote for npm install to work
Update:
In my project (MyProject) I tried to have a link to my module and I also installed the npm module (remote) at the same time. It seemed like it was working but now in MyProject when I click on class name in vscode to follow the class, I've made changes in it but the changes are not saved to the linked project but to the remote project in the node_modules folder.
So, my suggestion is that npm have an option in the packages.json for linked overrides like so:
  "dependencies": {
    "mymodule": "^1.2.3"
  }
  "linkedOverrides": {
    "mymodule": "local.version.number"
  }

That way someone can develop a project locally, and also use the npm module in a separate local project and also include a link to the npm module in the package.json that allows others to install the module.

Well, I've reinstalled the remote module using npm install myModule and package.json was updated and everything still seems to be working

Nevermind it's not working. Changing the npm files in the project does not seem to be saving the changes to the npm module project. When click following the class and opening the linked class in the project.
